# Macbook Pro 2018 blurry output on external HP Z23N display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hdmi, mojave

I'm on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) with Mojave (10.14). I'm trying to connect my MacBook to an external monitor (HP Z23N) through HDMI + Apple's usb-c adapter **A1621 EMC 2877**.

The connection works but the output is extremely blurry.

[image]

I know there are a lot of script for fixing this kind of problems. However, many of them do not work anymore and may lead to unexpected results. I'm looking for a fix working fine in that case.

EDIT: the monitor works fine if connected to a PC through DVI

EDIT:

Monitor with Debian

[image]

Monitor with MBP

[image]

MBP screen

[image]

Comment: It looks OK here - though it's quite small. Have you checked what the picture you posted looks like on both your screens? Did you check the monitor is displaying  in full resolution? - bearing in mind it's only a 1080p screen, so it's never going to be anything like as crisp as your MacBook's screen.

Comment: This is what it looks like to me compared to the normal text on my screen, zoomed to 500% size. They're not identical, but they are comparable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRQ6k.png

Comment: Thank you for your help. I posted other screenshots (also for PC/Debian) even if I'm not sure they can help more. I know it's just a 1080p, but fonts look blurry and really horrible : / color profile seems ok. I do not know hot to fix

Comment: Just for clarification, are you only using a USB-C to HDMI adapter, or is there any dock involved?

Comment: I'm using the Apple's official adapter **A1621 EMC 2877** This one: https://www.apple.com/it/shop/product/MJ1K2ZM/A/adattatore-multiporta-da-usb%E2%80%91c-ad-av-digitale?afid=p238%7CsiZYnVtNR-dc_mtid_187079nc38483_pcrid_207673144034_&cid=aos-it-kwgo-pla-btb--slid-----product-MJ1K2ZM/A-IT (updated also original post)

Comment: What are your Displays preferences set to? Is macOS trying to send it a >1080 signal?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder I’m not with my screen now. I should check but it should be a 1080.

Comment: @floatingpurr could you provide photos of the screen display instead of screenshots as you did above. We can't see a difference between screenshots. Are you using your external screen at its optimal resolution? Blurry screens are often the result of downscaling resolution. If you want to be sure, don't the OS deciding the optimal value and try different resolution to see how it goes.

Comment: I’ve already tried different resolutions by switching options in the monitor menu of Mojave with no luck. :(

Comment: @floatingpurr have you tried to connect your screen with a USB-C to display port adapter? It could eliminate a faulty HDMI cable or adapter. I just checked your screen connections options and dp is in the list.

Comment: I tried with UDB-C to mini display port with another screen (LCD Cinema Display) and everything works fine

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder screen mode is 1920x1080 60Hz. I have no idea about the signal from my MacBookPro.

Comment: This is a long shot but could you try go to Setting>Energy Saver> Disable Automatic graphics switching for both the battery and power adapter. Reboot and reset SMC. Then make sure both the options are disabled in settings. Then only plug in your display.

More info on SMC here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Comment: Have you tried toggling the font smoothing option in System Preferences > General?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work :/